# How do I install 'Make' without internet connection?

Tags: make

I need to install wifi drivers on my laptop, the drivers I have use 'Make' during the install process.

How can I download 'Make' without installing and save to usb (obviously using a pc with internet connection)?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu do you use? (16.04,18.04,)

Comment: Which are the drivers?

Comment: killer 1650 wifi card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask `apt-get` for the packages that will be installed like this:

`sudo apt-get --print-uris install make | cut -d"'" -f2 | grep http > /tmp/packages.list`

Then you copy that file and, on another computer you do:

`wget -i packages.list`

Then you move the .deb packages you just downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives` on the unconnected computer.

And run:

`sudo apt-get install make`

That should do it.

Comment: where will that save? How can I copy to usb and then install on the other pc?

Comment: I updated the answer to include all the steps.

Comment: actually the packages.list file is empty are running the command . .

Answer (score 1):

First, download the packages listed below

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libgcc1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/gcc-8-base_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

`make` requires `libc6`, `libc6` requires `libgcc1`, `libgcc1` requires `gcc-8-base`.

Copy these packages to a folder and transfer it to the pc on which they are to be installed.

Now, open a terminal into that folder and type the command

`sudo dpkg -i *`

Comment: I bricked my Ubuntu machine by doing this. There were issues with libc which the OS depended on, and after that it wouldn't boot.

I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but I am saying that anyone following your instructions had better know what they are doing (I didn't) or they could end up in the same situation as I did.

Comment: In my case I already had libc.so.6 installed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ so my first mistake was to try installing it without checking for its existence first. Installing make on its own without the other three packages worked.

Comment: @matt_rule, since the OP did not specify the version of Ubuntu he/she is using, i couldn't give a very specific answer. Apologies

Comment: It's not your fault it's mine :)