# How do I install make without internet on Ubuntu (with help from a windows 10 laptop that has internet)?

Tags: 20.04, make

[This link does not answer my problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193551/how-do-i-install-make-without-internet-connection). The first solution I've no idea how to work. The second one I attempted, but it bricked Ubuntu and I had to reinstall the OS.

My setup:
Desktop computer with Ubuntu installed (Linux version 5.4.0-2 genetic.
Ubuntu version: 20.04.1

Windows 10 laptop that has an internet connection.

I am trying to install drivers for the wifi adapter but I need to be able to make them. Make is not available so I need a way to transfer this from the Windows 10 laptop to the Ubuntu desktop with my USB key. I have tried Keryx but to no avail.

I've been trying for 6 hours now so would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: One simple solution is to share the Windows internet connection. A network cable is needed for that...but they are cheap and you can set up a network in much less than 6 hours.

Comment: *"The first solution I've no idea how to work.*" what part of this answer are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the network connected system was Ubuntu. Here's my process:

System A: network connection.

System B: needs network.

USB key Read/Writable by both A and B. FAT-32, ExFAT format. not NTFS.

Set P to the package to install.

Retry:

On System A:

Download P from https://packages.ubuntu.com Ensure the `.deb` file is stored on the USB key. Be sure to dl packages for your Ubuntu release.

If I knew how to list dependencies of a `.deb`, I would use it here, add dependencies to P, and go back to Retry.

Unmount the USB key, and move it to System B.

On System B:

`cd` to the USB key, probably `/media/$USER/...`.

Try to install P with

```
sudo dpkg --install *.deb
```

It will probably fail, issuing messages like "Package *foo* depends on *bar*, but *bar*  is not going to be installed". Add package *bar* to P, the list of packages to be installed.

`cd` away from the USB key.

Unmount (`umount`) the USB key, and move it back to System A.

Go back to Retry.

After about 7 cycles, you should have come to a successful `sudo dpkg --install *.deb`, or Something Is Awry.